# Why is 'root' keyword treated differently when it is called in Kivy?

Tags: python, kivy

[How to make circular progress bar in kivy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50543028/how-to-make-circular-progress-bar-in-kivy)

I have found a source above for circular progress bar and noted something weird.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.progressbar import ProgressBar
from kivy.core.text import Label as CoreLabel
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder
from kivy.graphics import Color, Ellipse, Rectangle
from kivy.clock import Clock


class CircularProgressBar(ProgressBar):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(CircularProgressBar, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        # Set constant for the bar thickness
        self.thickness = 40

        # Create a direct text representation
        self.label = CoreLabel(text="0%", font_size=self.thickness)

        # Initialise the texture_size variable
        self.texture_size = None

        # Refresh the text
        self.refresh_text()

        # Redraw on innit
        self.draw()

    def draw(self):

        with self.canvas:

            # Empty canvas instructions
            self.canvas.clear()

            # Draw no-progress circle
            Color(0.26, 0.26, 0.26)
            Ellipse(pos=self.pos, size=self.size)

            # Draw progress circle, small hack if there is no progress (angle_end = 0 results in full progress)
            Color(1, 0, 0)
            Ellipse(pos=self.pos, size=self.size,
                    angle_end=(0.001 if self.value_normalized == 0 else self.value_normalized*360))

            # Draw the inner circle (colour should be equal to the background)
            Color(0, 0, 0)
            Ellipse(pos=(self.pos[0] + self.thickness / 2, self.pos[1] + self.thickness / 2),
                    size=(self.size[0] - self.thickness, self.size[1] - self.thickness))

            # Center and draw the progress text
            Color(1, 1, 1, 1)
            Rectangle(texture=self.label.texture, size=self.texture_size,
                      pos=(self.size[0]/2 - self.texture_size[0]/2, self.size[1]/2 - self.texture_size[1]/2))

    def refresh_text(self):
        # Render the label
        self.label.refresh()

        # Set the texture size each refresh
        self.texture_size = list(self.label.texture.size)

    def set_value(self, value):
        # Update the progress bar value
        self.value = value

        # Update textual value and refresh the texture
        self.label.text = str(int(self.value_normalized*100)) + "%"
        self.refresh_text()

        # Draw all the elements
        self.draw()


class Main(App):

    def just_function(self):
        print(self.root) # <----- this will print None

    # Simple animation to show the circular progress bar in action
    def animate(self, dt):
        print(self.root) # <---- this prints CircularProgressBar object
        if self.root.value < 80:
            self.root.set_value(self.root.value + 1)
        else:
            self.root.set_value(0)

    # Simple layout for easy example
    def build(self):
        container = Builder.load_string(
            '''CircularProgressBar:
    size_hint: (None, None)
    height: 200
    width: 200
    max: 80''')

        # Animate the progress bar
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.animate, 0.1)
        print(self.root) # <---- this prints None
        self.just_function() # <---- this prints None
        return container


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Main().run()
```

When you take a look at `Main(App)`

In this source, `self.root` is considered as `CircularProgressBar` in here.

But, when I do `print(self.root)` it prints `None`.

It only recognize `CircularProgressBar` when `self.root` is in a function that is called by `Clock.scheduled_interval(func, rate)`.

Does anyone know what is happening in here?

Comment: You say: *But, when I do print(self.root) it prints None* and I wonder where in your code do you print?

Comment: @eyllanesc If I do `print(self.root)` inside `def animate(self.dt):`, it will print `CircularProgressBar object` and if I do it outside such as above `return container`, it prints `None`

Comment: please edit your question points where you get an incorrect output.

Comment: @eyllanesc it is funny because if I create a random function such as `def function(self):` and put `print(root)` it will also return `None`. It only returns `CircularProgressBar` if it is called by `Clock`

Comment: Could you say where you define that function and when you invoke it?

Comment: @eyllanesc I have just edited so you  can see where (in `Main`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The explanation is very simple and is clearly explained in the [docs](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.app.html#kivy.app.App.root):

> **root = None**
>
> The root widget returned by the build() method or by the load_kv()
>   method if the kv file contains a root widget.

From the above it is understood that the `root` is the element that is returned in the `build()` method, so before something returns that function the `root` will be `None`, so when you print `self.root` within `build()` or call a function that prints `self.root` before returning that function you will always get `None`. After returning the root it will be what you returned, that is, the `container` an object of the class `CircularProgressBar`.