# Display an image partially using stencilview

Tags: python, kivy

I have asked a question about making a progress bar using stencilview [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52657571/how-do-i-partially-display-an-image-in-kivy)

And I could make one successfully.

Now I am trying to make a partially displaying image display as below

[image: 1im]    [image: 2im]

1. First showing background image.
2. Progressively display certain part of filled image.
3. For example, fill up the arm then fill up the leg.
4. In this case, I am trying to fill up depending on which arm and leg parameter is inserted.

I am thinking maybe I should device the images as 5 parts and have stencilview for each of them, but I am asking if there is a way of doing it without putting 5 different images and stencilviews.

Here is what I've currently done for a single progress image.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.properties import StringProperty, NumericProperty
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder
from kivy.clock import Clock


class CLS_PROGRESS_IMAGE(FloatLayout):
    background = StringProperty(None)
    progress_image = StringProperty(None)
    max = NumericProperty(0.0)

    def __init__(self, font_size=20, **kwargs):
        super(CLS_PROGRESS_IMAGE, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.progress_event = None
        self.font_size = font_size
        self.firstDraw = True
        self.pbi = None
        self.rect = None
        self.bgi = None
        self.value = 0.0
        self.value_normalized = 0.0

        self.horizontal = False
        self.looping = True

        self.progress_event = Clock.schedule_interval(self._progress, 0.1)

    def draw(self):
        if self.firstDraw:
            self.ids.bgi.source=self.background
            self.ids.pbi.source = self.progress_image
            self.ids.lab.font_size = self.font_size
            self.ids.lab.text = str(int(self.value_normalized*100)) + "%"
            self.ids.sten.pos = self.pos

            if self.horizontal is True:
                self.ids.sten.width = self.size[0]*self.value_normalized
                self.ids.sten.height = self.size[1]
            else:
                self.ids.sten.height= self.size[1]*self.value_normalized
                self.ids.sten.width = self.size[0]
            self.firstDraw = False
        else:
            self.ids.sten.pos = self.pos
            self.ids.lab.text = str(int(self.value_normalized*100)) + "%"
            if self.horizontal is True:
                self.ids.sten.width = self.size[0]*self.value_normalized
            else:
                self.ids.sten.height= self.size[1]*self.value_normalized

    def set_value(self, value):
        self.value = value
        self.value_normalized = self.value / self.max
        self.draw()

    def _progress(self, dt):
        if self.value < self.max - 1:
            self.set_value(self.value + 1)
        else:
            if self.looping:
                self.value = 0
                self.set_value(self.value)
            else:
                self.set_value(self.max)
                self.progress_event.cancel()


# Demo
class DemoApp(App):

    def build(self):
        kv = Builder.load_string('''
<CLS_PROGRESS_IMAGE>:
    Image:
        id: bgi
        allow_stretch: True
        keep_ratio: False
    StencilView:
        id: sten
        horizontal: False
        size_hint: (None, None)
        size: (0, root.height) if self.horizontal else (root.width, 0)
        Image:
            id: pbi
            allow_stretch: True
            keep_ratio: False
            size_hint: (None, None)
            size: (root.width, root.height)
            pos: (root.pos[0], root.pos[1])
    Label:
        id: lab
        text: '0%'
        size_hint: (None, None)
        size: self.texture_size
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.5}

CLS_PROGRESS_IMAGE:
    size_hint: (None, None)
    height: 100
    width: 500
    max: 100
    background: '../images/empty.png'
    progress_image: '../images/filled.png'
    ''')
        return kv


if __name__ == '__main__':
    DemoApp().run()
```

Comment: provide a [mcve]

Comment: @eyllanesc Oh yes. I just did the one for a single image progression.

Comment: Does the filling need to be gradual, like a `ProgresBar`? Or can it be switched from non-filled to filled instantaneously?

Comment: @JohnAnderson It needs to be gradual.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though this is not "partially" progressing an image,

but I could successfully emulate this by just using multiple different images.

Basically, what I've done was progressing images that look like they are partially loaded

and continue the same progressing until I use up all the images I put in a list.

```
class CLS_PROGRESS_BODY(CLS_PROGRESS_IMAGE):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(CLS_PROGRESS_BODY, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.percentage_show = False
        self.image_list = None
        self.apply_adjustment = True
        self.progress_event.cancel()

        self.limitation = 0

    def start_progress(self):
        self.firstDraw = True
        self.progress_event.cancel()
        self.background= '../images/progress0.png'
        self.progress_image= '../images/progress1.png'
        self.image_list= ['../images/progress2.png', '../images/progress3.png', '../images/progress4.png',
                     '../images/progress5.png']
        if self.apply_adjustment:
            self.adjust_progress_position(self.progress_image)
        else:
            self.set_value(0)

        self.limitation = self.max * 0.8
        self.progress_event = Clock.schedule_interval(partial(self._progress, self.limitation), 0.1)

    def set_image_list(self, list_of_path):
        self.image_list = list_of_path

    def _progress(self, limit, dt):
        if self.value < self.max - 1 and self.value < limit:
            self.set_value(self.value + 1)
        else:
            self.set_value(self.max)
            self.progress_event.cancel()
            self.load_next_image()

    def load_next_image(self):
        if self.image_list:
            self.ids.bgi.source = self.ids.pbi.source
            self.ids.pbi.source = self.image_list.pop(0)
            if self.apply_adjustment:
                self.adjust_progress_position(self.ids.pbi.source)
            else:
                self.set_value(0)
            self.progress_event = Clock.schedule_interval(partial(self._progress, self.limitation), 0.1)
        else:
            if self.looping:
                self.start_progress()
```